# Reproducible replays of single-threaded write logs using Clojure STM

Tags: parallel-processing, clojure, stm

I'm working on a project that replays an event log (flat file format, for historical reasons) that should produce a resulting model identical to the legacy code, which is single-threaded. I'm trying to figure out good ways to speed this up; obviously the parsing and some of the validation can be parallelized, which brings them down to maybe 10% of the total time including I/O, but much of the validation is ordering-specific, and allowing reordering of events could result in unexpected validation failures, or worse, silently different results.

This seems like a job for Software Transactional Memory, since this is basically just a classic case of transactions just like databases. Except it isn't: this is offline processing, not online; the purpose of parallelizing this is to maximize deserialization speed, which effectively maximizes write contention and also the chance for reordering. (And these replays will occur repeatedly, so even a 0.1% chance of trouble per run is too high.) And Clojure's STM is of course specifically designed to retry transactions *from a later basis* if there's conflict in the refs — reordering semantically-related events. (This is fine in online transaction processing, where there is by definition no way to tell which event should run first. It's not fine when there is already a set ordering.) There are options to set minimum and maximum basis histories for each ref, which could potentially help, but seem unable to completely prevent this in general.

Is there a robust, principled way to still make this work (exploiting the concurrency of unrelated writes to different refs), or is it fundamentally a Hard™ problem? Or, equivalently, is STM actually the right hammer for this nail?

Comment: Is your current fastest correct implementation i/o bound, or compute bound, or something else?

Comment: Compute bound, by about an order of magnitude.

Comment: In that case, I'd peek at `visualvm` just to make sure nothing silly is bottlenecking it. There's often some boxed math or slow path in a data structure somewhere that can be avoided to speed things up.

Answer (score 2):

It seems the transaction part must be serialized in a single thread to guarantee the same ordering.  However, all pre-processing (and post-processing?) could be parallelized for a nice speedup.

A. Pre-proc:

1. Read the source file in large chunks of data as a lazy stream of bytes.
2. Use a thread pool of workers to parse the text into a stream of small, efficient events.

B. Tx:

3. A single thread performs the transactions into a mutable data store (Clojure `atom` or real DB or...?).  Since a single thread will have no contention (i.e. no aborted transactions or re-trys) it will be very fast (please see many YouTube videos about the LMax Exchange from Martin Thompson and Dave Farley).

C. Post-Proc:

4. This could also be parallelized if desired.

For (A), you could use the `pmap` function to get started, or just jump into the excellent [Claypoole library](https://github.com/clj-commons/claypoole).

Comment: I'd forgotten about LMax. That may have some good tips, so thanks!